# how to run update query for all values fetch by previous query

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

I want to run an sql select query which fetches P_no and after that an update query is run for it. It always update only 1 value.

```
$d=date('Y-m-d');
$qu="select P_no from date_summary where `Nextcall_1`='$d' or 
`Nextcall_2`='$d' or `Nextcall_3`='$d' or `Nextcall_4`='$d' 
or`Nextcall_5`='$d' or `Nextcall_6`='$d' or `Nextcall_7`='$d' or 
`Nextcall_8`='$d' or `Nextcall_9`='$d' or `Nextcall_10`='$d' or 
`Nextcall_11`='$d'";
 $res=mysqli_query($con,$qu);
if($res && mysqli_num_rows($res)>0)
 {
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
   {
      $p1=$row["P_no"]; 
       $qu="update notification_status set Noti_status='Unchecked' where 
       P_no=$p1";
       $res=mysqli_query($con,$qu);
  }
}
```

Comment: is your select query returning multiple records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `in` operator:

```
UPDATE notification_status
SET    noti_status='Unchecked'
WHERE  p_no IN (SELECT p_no FROM date_summary WHERE /* etc... */)
```